# Node.JS Org-scoped package - error when 'require()'

Tags: node.js, node-modules, require

Context: Node.JS

I am having an error invoking 'require()' for an ORGANIZATION-SCOPED Package (from NodeJS.com)

```
$ pwd
/Users/Sarma

$ node
> module.paths
[ '/Users/Sarma/repl/node_modules',
  '/Users/Sarma/node_modules',
  '/Users/node_modules',
  '/node_modules',
  '/usr/local/lib/node_modules',
  '/Users/Sarma/.node_modules',
  '/Users/Sarma/.node_libraries',
  '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.2.1/lib/node' ]

> require('@asux.org/cli-npm')
Error: Cannot find module '@asux.org/cli-npm'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

Any Tips on how to solve this?

To investigate myself, I searched '/' for 'loader.js' and found nothing (other than under XCode and VSC).

```
$ pwd
/Users/Sarma
$ ls -la node_modules 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  12 Sarma  staff   384 Apr  6 22:22 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 72 Sarma  staff  2304 Apr  6 22:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 Sarma  staff    96 Apr  6 22:22 .bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 Sarma  staff    96 Apr  6 22:22 @asux.org
drwxr-xr-x   3 Sarma  staff    96 Apr  6 22:22 @types
drwxr-xr-x   7 Sarma  staff   224 Apr  6 22:22 ansi-styles
drwxr-xr-x   7 Sarma  staff   224 Apr  6 22:22 chalk
drwxr-xr-x   9 Sarma  staff   288 Apr  6 22:22 color-convert
drwxr-xr-x   6 Sarma  staff   192 Apr  6 22:22 color-name
drwxr-xr-x   8 Sarma  staff   256 Apr  6 22:22 commander
drwxr-xr-x   7 Sarma  staff   224 Apr  6 22:22 has-flag
drwxr-xr-x   7 Sarma  staff   224 Apr  6 22:22 supports-color
$ ls -la node_modules/@asux.org/cli-npm 
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  8 Sarma  staff   256 Apr  6 22:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 Sarma  staff    96 Apr  6 22:22 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 Sarma  staff  3834 Oct 26  1985 HISTORY
-rw-r--r--  1 Sarma  staff  1516 Oct 26  1985 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x  5 Sarma  staff   160 Apr  6 22:22 bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 Sarma  staff    96 Apr  6 22:22 node_modules
-rw-r--r--  1 Sarma  staff   375 Apr  6 22:22 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--  1 Sarma  staff  2100 Apr  6 22:22 package.json
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In package.json..
I was missing the obvious (in hindsight).

```
"main": "bin/asux_module.js",
```

Once I added it, require() was successful.